# "Correct" way to lookup Cloud Service Configurations from Java in AEM 6

Tags: java, aem

AEM's Cloud Services API isn't terribly well documented, and provides a number of somewhat awkward to use methods that can be used to find a given `Configuration` from a resource. Below are a few examples I've found "in the wild" that do this.

**Method 1:** Getting all `Configurations` and iterating them until a named config is found:

```
public static Configuration findConfiguration(ConfigurationManager configurationManager, Resource resource, String serviceName) {
    Iterator configurations = configurationManager.getConfigurations(resource);
    while (configurations.hasNext()) {
        Configuration configuration = (Configuration) configurations.next();
        if (serviceName.equals(configuration.get("cq:cloudservicename", ""))) {
            return configuration;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

**Method 2:** Lookup all the `cq:cloudserviceconfigs` that apply to the resource and ask for the one you want:

```
public static Configuration findConfiguration(ConfigurationManager configurationManager, Resource resource, String serviceName) {
    HierarchyNodeInheritanceValueMap pageProperties = 
        new HierarchyNodeInheritanceValueMap(resource);

    String[] allServices = 
        pageProperties.getInherited("cq:cloudserviceconfigs", new String[0]);

    return configurationManager.getConfiguration(serviceName, allServices);
}
```

**Method 3:** Similar to method 2, but looks like it'll only work if the requested config is also defined on the first parent that has a `cq:cloudserviceconfigs` property?

```
public static Configuration findConfiguration(ConfigurationManager configurationManager, Resource resource, String serviceName) {

    Resource configurationResource = 
        configurationManager.getConfigurationResource(resource);

    if (configurationResource != null) {
        String[] cloudServiceConfigs = configurationResource.adaptTo(Page.class)
            .getProperties().get("cq:cloudserviceconfigs", String[].class);

        if (cloudServiceConfigs != null && cloudServiceConfigs.length > 0) {
            return configurationManager.getConfiguration(serviceName, cloudServiceConfigs);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

I find it odd that whoever designed this interface didn't simply add a method like `Configuration ConfigurationManager#getService(Resource resource, String serviceName)` - the hoops you have to jump through to achieve what seems like a common use case are frustrating, but that's how it is apparently.

So my question is this:

1. Is there a better API or library to use than `ConfigurationManager` for looking up a specific cloud service config for a page or resource?
2. If not, what is good, robust, performant way of using `ConfigurationManager` to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: from adobe's own code, method2 seems to be standard way of doing it.